# Why `SockJS 1.0.3` is not loading correctly into Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, sockjs

I am using `sockjs-1.0.3.js` in Eclipse. I worked with `sockjs-0.3.4.js` before and the intelisense and `Ctrl+Click` code browsing works fine.  But with 1.0.3, it doesn't work. And seems the js parsing is incorrect. See below:

[image]

### ADD 1

AMD, CommonJS and UMD:
http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/

Answer (score 0):

SockJS is now properly wrapped in a UMD closure and doesn't leak global variables.

Comment: Thanks. I am not quite sure what UMD closure is because I am new to JS. But does it cause the intellisense to fail in Eclipse? How can I  jump from the object to its definition with `Ctrl+Click`?